# Android Record a video

Tags: android, record, video-recording

I am trying to record a video on my android project.

I have found some exemples on the internet but nothing is working.
Normaly, i have to use the `MediaRecorder`

Can you give me a simple exemple, i don't need to visualise the video when is token, only to register it on my sdcard, that's all.

Here is an exemple of what I am trying to do:

```
public class VideoCapture extends Activity {  

    MediaRecorder recorder;  
    Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);  
    Button buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();  
        initRecorder();  
    }  

    private void initRecorder() {  
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);  
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);  
        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);  
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");  
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000);  
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000);  
    }  

    private void prepareRecorder() {  
        try {  
            recorder.prepare();  
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            finish();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            finish();  
        }  
    }  

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()

            {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v)  
        {  
        initRecorder();  
            prepareRecorder();  
        }});  

    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v)  
        {  
            recorder.stop();  
        }
    }); 
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{test.milos.net/test.milos.net.TestVideoNetActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.milos.net.TestVideoNetActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/test.milos.net-2.apk]
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.milos.net.TestVideoNetActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/test.milos.net-2.apk]
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
12-25 22:04:24.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: If you show what exactly you tried and what exactly didn't work we can help you. Providing you with yet another example too the many you said you found won't solve anything for you. You probably misunderstand something when multiple examples don't work.

Comment: Here is my code @alextsc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guessed, you do a few things wrong that don't have anything to do with the actual video recording.

First problem:

```
Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);  
Button buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);
```

You can't call `findViewById()` here. `findViewById()` only searches in the activities current view hierachy. At the point where your class gets instatiated, there is no view hierachy present. These class members will always be null, because that is what gets returned if the view cannot be found. You can keep the variable declaration, but move the search part into `onCreate()`, after you call `setContentView()`, for example like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);  
buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);
```

Same goes for your two `setOnClickListener()` calls on the bottom. They have to be inside a method. I'd suggest moving these two blocks into `onCreate()` as well, after the `findViewById()` calls.

---

Edit: The stacktrace indicates that your app tries to run an activity named `TestVideoNetActivity`. Your actual activity is named `VideoCapture`.

Open your AndroidManifest and look for a part that looks like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TestVideoNetActivity"
        ... >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Change *TestVideoNetActivity* to *VideoCapture*. Also make sure that your packages match, 
there should be a line `package="X"` at the top of your manifest and a line `package X;` at the top of your java source file. Make sure these have the same value for X.

---

Edit 2: Your second stacktrace indicates that `setAudioSource()` failed. All I can think of is that you don't have the correct permissions set to access the microphone. Add the following lines to your android-manifest *(this includes the camera permission too, since you need that as well)*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Add them inside the `<manifest>` tag, but outside of the `<application>` tag. E.g. after the `<uses-sdk>` line, if you got one (is included by default I believe).

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for this help. I have done it but my programm is still coloing immediately with an error.

Comment: What error are you facing? A "force close" dialog? In this case can you provide a stacktrace? You can get that from the logcat, in eclipse use `Window -> Show View -> Logcat`. A system log should appear. Run your app and let it crash. A big red blob should appear inside the log. Please post this.

Comment: The logcat is to big for an comment, here is the link, i uploaded a Word file withe the errors: [link](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=AZD8QV2T)

Thanks again for our big help.

Comment: Yes, comments are not suited for this. You can edit it into your question in the future though, did it for you now. I'll edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right.... I changed this but the error is still there.... hmmm..... I will put the new logcat on my question.

Comment: Hm, i can't do id, here is the link: [linh](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=KBQBAOY7)

Thank you again

Comment: Oh of corse, i forget to do this.... 
Now, i have a problem with my recorder.prepare();

I uploaded the new logcat. [link](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=F494F6MG)

Comment: Somebody can please help me??